# find surface area using double integral of: $\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}+z=1$ and plane $x+2z+1=0$

Tags: calculus

So I have to find surface area using double integral of: $\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}+z=1$ above the plane $x+2z+1=0$. I drew the picture and I see that an ellipse is the intersection between the cone and plane.

Now, $z(x,y)=1-\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$ and from $z$ I will find partial derivatives by $x$ and $y$ and put them in a standard formula. Now what is giving me trouble is when I have to project into the x-y plane. I can't seem to understand over which area should I integrate.. Is it the ellipse?

------------------------EDIT: based on Math Lover comment------------------------

So I expressed $z$'s from cone and plane equation and set them equal in order to get the ellipse equation. At the end I got $\frac{(\sqrt{3}x-9)^2}{18}+\frac{y^2}{\frac{9}{2}}=1$. Then I performed the change of variables $x=\frac{9+\sqrt{18}u}{\sqrt{3}}$, $y=\frac{\sqrt{9}}{\sqrt{2}}v$ in order to get unit circle in $u-v $ coordinate system. Also I have found the Jacobian $\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}$. Finally at the end I used polar coordinates and that's it. Is this the right way to do so?

Comment: do you mean the area of $\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}+z=1$ above the plane? Or the intersecting ellipse? The problem is worded a bit ambiguously.

Comment: yes above the plane

Comment: Yes of course you have to integrate over the ellipse and the factor you multiply by, $dS = \sqrt{1 + (\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})^2 + (\frac{\partial z}{\partial y})^2} \, \, dx \, dy$ translates that to the surface area of the cone. But it is easier to parametrize in polar coordinates so you don't have to worry about finding limits of $x, y$. Let me know if it is clear or you need further help.

Comment: I edited the post based on your comment. I would appreciate it if you could check it out..

Comment: @untitled I did not get a notification on your comment otherwise I would have checked. Try and add name when you send comment. Sometimes the notification does not work otherwise.

Comment: @MathLover I will note that

Comment: OK I just added corrections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something went wrong in one of your steps. I get a different equation for ellipse.

Parametrization of the cone, $ \ c(t) = (r \cos t, r \sin t, 1 - r)$.

So you can easily find $|c'_{t} \times c'_{r}| = r \sqrt2$

So surface area of the cone $S = \sqrt2 \iint_D r \ dr \ dt$

Where $D$ is the projection of the intersection of the cone and the plane in $XY$ plane. So our next step is to find the area of the intersection.

Intersection of cone and the plane is given by,

$1 + \frac{1+x}{2} = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \implies 3x^2 - 6x + 4y^2 = 9$

So equation of ellipse is $ \ \frac{(x-1)^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{3} = 1$

We know the area of the ellipse with semi-major and semi-minor axes lengths of $a$ and $b$ is $\pi ab = 2 \sqrt3 \ \pi$

But if you need to solve this by integral then,

Using substitution, $x = 1 + 2 \ r \cos t, y = \sqrt3 \ r \sin t$, our new domain is a circle of unit radius.

$|J| = 2 \sqrt3 \ r$

So the area of ellipse $\displaystyle \iint_D dx \ dy = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 2 \sqrt3 \ r \ dr \ dt = 2 \pi \sqrt3$

So surface area of the cone $S = 2 \pi \sqrt6$